# trying to compare user input with a text file and then read the values of numbers from that point on java

Tags: java, file-io, user-input

```
while(inFile.hasNext())
{
    String Desnation = inFile.next();

    if(givenLocation.equalsIgnoreCase(Desnation))
    {
        int num1 = inFile.nextLine();
        int num2 = inFile.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Yay!");
    }
}
```

It is saying that it can't convert a string to an int so tried to parse it before hand but the substring wasn't registering the input from user.

Answer (score 2):

You have to convert String into Integer:

```
try {
    int num1 = Integer.parseInt(inFile.nextLine());
    int num2 = Integer.parseInt(inFile.nextLine());
} catch(NumberFormatException e) {
    //handle exception, ex print some text
}
```

BTW as [Java naming convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367) says:

> Except for variables, all instance, class, and class constants are in mixed case with a lowercase first letter. Internal words start with capital letters. Variable names should not start with underscore _ or dollar sign $ characters, even though both are allowed.

consider changing
    Desnation 
to

```
desnation
```

Comment: I wouldn't say `Java variables should start with a lowercase`, but instead `it is common coding practice that local variables in Java begin with a lower case letter`.